# App engine remote shell via a proxy when using Python

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy

I am using the Google Appengine remote shell, with Python. I am walking through an entire database table updating all my entities, and I am doing this in 500 entity chunks. This is all working fine. The task involves

- fire up the remote shell
- kick off the job
- wait 10 minutes
- rinse, repeat

I'd like to keep this up while I'm at work, and just do it in the background, without of course impacting my productivity :-). What's getting in my way is the firewall, which prevents this sort of transfer of data, when logged in over VPN.

So is there a way to do this, like in a separate Emacs shell? If I had two computers, I'd just run this thing on my spare, but I don't. (I do have an iPad, but I doubt that helps).

I may be misunderstanding the core issues, and hence, my question.

Comment: Why are you doing it over remote_api? This involves transferring all your data to your machine and back - it would make a lot more sense to do the processing on App Engine, as Daniel suggests.

Comment: Each entity in one table gives me data to search for a Wikipedia page. I parse the search result page, and potentially come up with the url of the "right" Wikipedia page. I then store that url in another table.  Each invocation of the remote api processes about 800  entries. After about 10 times or less I bump up against my daily quota for "write" operations.  I suppose if I set this up with   mapreduce, I could fire it up, and let it spin till it hit the quota. Less labor intensive, although it'll probably take the same number of days. I'm hesitant to switch to mapreduce in midstream. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the remote shell, it'll probably be easier - and certainly quicker - to run the job entirely on the server via the [mapreduce API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).

Comment: I'll definitely bite the bullet and learn mapreduce for my next job, which may be to combine two tables into one. I'll need to do that in an effort to be more efficient about using up my datastore read operation daily quota. Oh, for the days before quotas!